# Sending QVideoFrame through QTcpSocket

Tags: qt

I've been writing an application for mobile streaming.
And now I got a problem with sending *QVideoFrame*. I need to convert it to *char** for sending, so I used *bits()* method, but it seems to be wrong.
This is the code:

```
void FilterRunnable::sendFrame(QVideoFrame *frame)
{
    QByteArray block;
    QDataStream stream(&block,QIODevice::WriteOnly);

    frame->map(QAbstractVideoBuffer::ReadOnly);

    stream << qint16(0) << (char*)frame->bits();
    stream.device()->seek(0);
    stream << qint16(block.size() - sizeof(qint16));

    skt.write(block);

    frame->unmap();
}
```

So the question is, How to send QVideoFrame through QTcpSocket? Is it actually possible?

Comment: At what stage are you having an issue? Is it when the frame is received? Can you convert it to bits and then back locally successfully?

Comment: I have a QVideoFilterRunnable which filtres every single QVideoFrame before it is shown.This filter don't change frame, it just sends it to the server, so after filtering frame can be shown. Problem is that sending bits() is not enough, I can't build Frame on the server using only data from bits().

Comment: What does the code look like on the server?

Comment: There's a function that reads data from socket and sends that data to anouther function which handles that data.
handlePacket(QByteArray packet){
// no idea how to build frame from that ByteArray
}

Comment: The only thing I can think of off the top of my head is that the conversion from `uchar *` (returned from the `->bits()`) to `char *` is causing an issue.

Comment: That conversion is not the case. Actual problem is that QVideoFrame consist of a  big bunch of data, and fuction bits() returns only a part of the whole data. So if i want to build a frame on the server I have find a way to send whole data.

Comment: Hey, could you find a solution to this problem? I have been trying to achieve the same and tried converting QVideoFrame to QImage and then send it over network but it crashes the application. If you could share what you did to overcome your problem.

Comment: @VivekVaishya Unfortunately, I was not able to find a solution for this problem

Answer (score 1):

`QDataStream::operator<<(const char * s)` writes a zero terminated string (see [documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html#operator-lt-lt-12)) so if you encounter a zero byte in the data in the frame it will be truncated. Try `writeBytes`.